# Adding a new column in one DataFrame where values are based from a second DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have two DataFrames, `df_a` is the DataFrame we want to manipulate. I want to add a new column but the values are found in a second DataFrame with a similar column name.

Let me expound.

`df_a` contains

```
_ | Code | Speed | Velocity |
0 |  DA  |   23  |    22    |
1 |  ES  |   23  |    22    |
2 |  DA  |   23  |    22    |
3 |  GA  |   23  |    22    |
4 |  NU  |   23  |    22    |
```

`df_b` contains

```
_ | Code |     Name    |
0 |  DA  |   DinoAero  |
1 |  ES  |    Espeed   |
2 |  GA  |    GeoArk   |
3 |  NU  |  NewUnicorn |
```

I want to merge or concatenate these two DataFrames that the result should look like this:

```
_ | Code |     Name     | Speed | Velocity |
0 |  DA  |   DinoAero   |   23  |    22    |
1 |  ES  |    Espeed    |   23  |    22    |
2 |  DA  |   DinoAero   |   23  |    22    |
3 |  GA  |    GeoArk    |   23  |    22    |
4 |  NU  |  NewUnicorn  |   23  |    22    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) (which is similar to a SQL join).

In your case:

```py
new_df = pd.merge(df_a,df_b,how='left',on='Code')
new_df = new_df[['Code','Name','Speed','Velocity']] # if you want to re-arrange the columns in your order
```